# Error accessing removable drive (SSD M2 1TB)

Tags: usb, hard-drive, ssd, m2

I'm having problems trying to access and even format an M.2 SSD (whether using it through an external case or connected directly to the board.
Every time I try to access or even format, the error described below appears:

```
An error occurred while accessing 'Removable Media 953.9 GiB',   
the system reported: The requested operation failed:  
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /run/media/cerberus/A2F2-2C40: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Could anyone help me with this?

I thank you for your attention.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Is this external device using a USB-C cable?

Comment: Many SSD, even new ones need a firmware update. Do you have latest firmware?  Compare revision with latest by vendor: `udisksctl status` or install nvme `sudo apt install nvme-cli` and `sudo nvme list`